# How to use sorting functionto sort the cities' populations in ascending order?

Tags: javascript

I just learn about Introduction to Web Cartography - Part 1 with

Exercise 3: First Coding, now I have problem with How to use sorting function  to sort the cities' populations in ascending order?Please help me!

[image]

Comment: Please provide the code what you try and necessary links.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple. Array has [built-in sort function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort). You load data first, then call sort:

```js
items.sort((a, b) => a.population - b.population)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two steps to this problem.

First we must structure the provided data in a way that will be easy to programmatically traverse and ultimately to sort.

Lets store each table row in an object, with the property keys matching the columns. Your data object should look something like this:

```
const data = [
    { 
    city: 'Zurich',
    lat: 47,
    long: 9,
    population: 402762
  },
  { 
    city: 'Tokyo',
    lat: 36,
    long: 140,
    population: 9467490
  },
  { 
    city: 'New York',
    lat: 43,
    long: -75,
    population: 8537673
  },
  { 
    city: 'Sydney',
    lat: -33,
    long: 151,
    population: 5005400
  },
  // ... rest of data
];
```

Then we can simply sort this data using the [Array.prototype.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function as follows:

```
data.sort(function(cityA, cityB) { return cityA.population > cityB.population });
```

This can be made even clearer by using an arrow functions!

```
data.sort((cityA, cityB) => cityA.population > cityB.population);
```